# Adding the integer till it is lesser than given value and display only those lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

Help me display all the `JOB_ID` till the `Nodes_req` is lesser than node available.

i.e add all the columns of `Nodes_req` till it is lesser than `Nodes_avail` then display only the `JOB_ID`

`Nodes_avail`=`50`

```
JOB_ID     | Tasks      | ptile      | Nodes_req
168797     | 126        | 16         | 8
168798     | 126        | 16         | 8
168799     | 126        | 16         | 8
168800     | 126        | 16         | 8
168801     | 126        | 16         | 8
168802     | 126        | 16         | 8
168811     | 126        | 16         | 8
```

expected output is "`168797 168798 168799 168800 168801 168802`" as

`8*7 = 56` which is greater than `50` so display only till `168802`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{if((sum+=$7)<50)print}' File
```

OR even shorter:

```
awk '(sum+=$7)<50' File
```

**Sample:**

```
$ awk '{if((sum+=$7)<50)print}' File
JOB_ID     | Tasks      | ptile      | Nodes_req
168797     | 126        | 16         | 8
168798     | 126        | 16         | 8
168799     | 126        | 16         | 8
168800     | 126        | 16         | 8
168801     | 126        | 16         | 8
168802     | 126        | 16         | 8
```

Just add the `7th` field value to a variable `sum` (We can also use `$NF` instead of `$7`, it will take last field). If `sum` is less than `50`, print the line.
Hope it helps!

Comment: If i supply a interger it works but variable doesn't work, Please help

working:-
$ awk '{if((sum+=$7)<50)print}' File--> works

not working:-
$ nodes=50
$ echo $nodes
$ 50
awk '{if((sum+=$7)<$nodes)print}' File ##doesn't work

Comment: hi, u can do it like this: node=50; awk -v n=$node '(sum+=$7)<n' File (bash variable cannot be used directly, so copy $node to the awk variable n and use n.

Comment: Or like this: awk -v node=50 '(sum+=$7)<node' File